# How to filter out specific entries in tree created by <DataFolder_object>.getNodeDelegate()

Tags: java, netbeans, rcp, netbeans-platform

i have a

```
class PovrayLogicalView implements LogicalViewProvider {
```

`...`

```
    @Override
    public Node createLogicalView() {
        FileObject scenes = ...get folder object from a project instance...
        DataFolder scenesDataObject = DataFolder.findFolder(scenes);
        Node scenesFolderNode = scenesDataObject.getNodeDelegate();
        return scenesFolderNode;
    }
```

`...`

```
}
```

With it i am getting `scenes` directory and all it's children in Project Tree Viewer of my RCP application. The only unsatisfying thing - it showes there *all* subdirectories and files under `scenes` root - even hidden ones.

I have tried to remove children explicitly, by

```
scenesFolderNode.getChildren().remove(scenesFolderNode.getChildren().getNodes());
```

but the .remove() method always returning false, meaning it can't remove any child nodes. Why? What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a [FilterNode](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqNodesDecorating) for this.